# How to unlink() by its name without knowing the file extention?

Tags: php, file, unlink

**In short**

We have a a file called `clients.(unique parameter)`. And now we want to `unlink()` it, but as we don't know the file extension, how do we succeed?

**Longer story**

I have a cache system, where the DB query in `md5()` is the filename and the cache expiration date is the extension.

**Example:** `896794414217d16423c6904d13e3b16d.3600`

But sometimes the expiration dates change. So for the ultimate solution, the file extension should be ignored.

The only way I could think of is to search the directory and match the filenames, then get the file extension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [`glob()`:](http://php.net/manual/function.glob.php)

```
$files = glob("/path/to/clients.*");
foreach ($files as $file) {
  unlink($file);
}
```

If you need to, you can check the `filemtime()` of each file returned by the `glob()` to sort them so that you only delete the oldest, for example.

```
// Example: Delete those older than 2 days:
$files = glob("./clients.*");
foreach ($files as $file) {
   if (filemtime($file) < time() - (86400 * 2)) {
     unlink($file);
   }
}
```

Comment: Ty, works great. I guess there is no neater way, then foreach loop. Though it is still better then readdir() loop. Luckly, I dont have to delete caches manually very often, so optimizing this isn't prio.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your guess to search the directory for a matching file name. There are multiple approaches you could take:

`readdir` the folder in question

`glob` as suggested by Micheal

You could also get the output of `ls {$target_dir} | grep {$file_first_part}` and then unlink the resulting string (assuming a match is found).